# Is the function measurable with respect to product measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

$\left (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M},\mu \right )$ is a Lebesgue measure space and $f$
is Lebesgue measurable on $\mathbb{R}.$Prove the equality $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}|f(x)|dx=\int^{\infty}_{0}\mu(\{x:|f(x)|\ge t\})dt.$$

---

Since $|f(x)|=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathbf {I_\left\{ \left ( x,t \right ):|f(x)|\ge t\ge 0\right\}}dt$,
I want to apply the Fubini theorem on $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}|f(x)|dx=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\left (\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathbf {I_\left\{ \left ( x,t \right ):|f(x)|\ge t\ge 0\right\}}dt \right) dx.$$ But how can I illustrate the function $\mathbf {I_\left\{ \left ( x,t \right ):|f(x)|\ge t\ge 0\right\}}$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma \left (\mathcal{M}\times \mathcal{M} \right ),$ that is ,  the set $\left\{ \left ( x,t \right ):|f(x)|\ge t\ge 0\right\} \in \sigma \left (\mathcal{M}\times \mathcal{M} \right ) ?$

Comment: I think the following maybe useful. Suppose $f_{n}$ is a sequence of non-negative measurable simple functions converging pointwise increasingly to $|f|$. 
$$ \textrm {Let} \quad E = \{ (x,t)\ ||f(x)|\ge t\ge 0 \},\quad E_{n} = \{ (x,t)\ | f_{n}(x)\ge t\ge 0 \}.$$
then $E = \cup_{n} E_n$ and $E_{n}$ is a finite union of rectangles.Thus,$E$ is measurable.

Comment: Your comment seems correct to me, I agree $E$ should be measurable by that argument